# Hide folder in Document Library from everyone including site admin except for specific users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, access

I have created a subsite for our finance people and company executives on SharePoint under office 365.

For a specific folder, I removed inheritance and specifically granted permissions to just the few people that need to access it. When I check permissions for other people in the company, they have no access. However, when I check permissions for myself I see this:

**Permission levels given to Brian Beaudet:**
None

**The following factors also affect the level of access for Brian Beaudet**: A super long list of Allow.

I am listed as the Owner of this particular subsite as well as having the SharePoint administrator role.

How do I exclude myself completely from just this folder so I cannot access sensitive data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admins always can get in. If you want to block admin access, you have two main options:

1. Use a 3rd party encryption tool
2. Don't store it in SharePoint